# Spamassassin regex header rule not working

Tags: regex, perl, spamassassin

I'm new to Spamassassin, regex and Perl, so I'd appreciate some help. I was trying to add a spam score to all emails whose senders follow a certain pattern, namely:
`name.surname.@example.com`.
This is what I came up with

```
header NAME_DOT_SURNAME_DOT_FQDN From=~((?:[a-z]+))(\\.)((?:[a-z]+))(\\.)(@)((?:[a-z][a-z\\.\\d\\-]+)\\.(?:[a-z][a-z\\-]+))(?![\\w\\.])
score NAME_DOT_SURNAME_DOT_FQDN 3.0
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. When I run `spamassassin --lint` i get the following output:

```
Feb 12 12:52:59.521 [32767] warn: Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at /etc/spamassassin/local.cf, rule NAME_DOT_SURNAME_DOT_FQDN, line 1.
Feb 12 12:52:59.522 [32767] warn: rules: failed to compile Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Check::_head_tests_0_3, skipping:
Feb 12 12:52:59.522 [32767] warn:  (Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/: [...][a-z]+) <-- HERE )(\\.)((/ at /etc/spamassassin/local.cf, rule NAME_DOT_SURNAME_DOT_FQDN, line 1.)
Feb 12 12:52:59.620 [32767] warn: lint: 1 issues detected, please rerun with debug enabled for more information
```

Running `spamassassin --lint -D` just produces a wall of text that contains the same error.
Can anyone please point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know SpamAssassin, but could it be that it requires `/` `/` around the regex?

Because the error message indicates Perl is treating `?` as the regex delimiter, leading to a regex of:

```
?:[a-z]+))(\\.)((?
#-------^ unmatched ')'
```

So what I'd try is:

```
header NAME_DOT_SURNAME_DOT_FQDN From=~/((?:[a-z]+))(\\.)((?:[a-z]+))(\\.)(@)((?:[a-z][a-z\\.\\d\\-]+)\\.(?:[a-z][a-z\\-]+))(?![\\w\\.])/
```

Also, those doubled backslashes look suspicious. Are you sure you don't mean e.g. `\w` instead of `\\w`?